# Send message to Slack using webhook in flask

Tags: flask

I am creating an app using Flask, by which I want to send message to a Slack channel, Also i need to use Webhook to send messages.  If there is any other option, please add

Comment: Kindly share your code that you have tried till now. It will be easy for others to help you with your code

Comment: I have no idea how to do. Just need some idea to start with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As I have worked on the above topic I will trying to ans with proper details**
*I am writing this as i have done in my project*

- Create an App

  - https://api.slack.com/apps
- Select your app
- Click on `Basic Information`

  - You will find `keys` and other details
- Click on `OAuth & Permissions`

  - add scopes
  - add redirect url

    - Partial match also works
- Using `Slack Oauth2` to get access of the Slack channel

  - Doc for help: https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth
  - Make a frontend request: `"https://slack.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=" + slack_client_id + "&scope=incoming-webhook&redirect_uri=" + slack_redirect_url`

    - You will need to select a `Slack Workspace` and a `Channel` from the Workspace
    - Will get `Code` from above request and make a Backend request
  - Make a backend POST Request: `'''https://slack.com/api/oauth.access?client_id=''' + slack_client_id + '''&client_secret=''' + slack_client_secret + '''&code=''' + code + '''&redirect_uri=''' + slack_redirect_url`
  - Extract `incoming_webhook` form the above response
- Send Message

  - `payload = '{ "text": "%s" }' % message`
  - `requests.request("POST", incoming_webhook, data=payload)`

Comment: You don't need a flask to do this, python is sufficient, you can use flask if you want to.

Comment: Thanks, you had a great explanation